# Lotus Notes Agent - Java Security Error

Tags: java, swing, lotus, agent

I have a Lotus Notes Agent written in Java which should pop up a message to the user after it is executed by clicking a button in the Notes client. Trying to display the pop-up causes an error which I see in the Java Debug console as :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.superDotCheckPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1449)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkRuntimePermission(AppletSecurity.java:1311)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1611)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1464)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:756)
at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:99)
at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:279)
at ClipboardTest.main(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My agent code is

```
    import lotus.domino.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

    public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

public void NotesMain() {

  try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      // (Your code goes here)
      Document cdoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
      String[] notesURL = new String[] {cdoc.getNotesURL()};
      ClipboardTest.main(notesURL);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"message","title",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

  } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}
}

I have manager access to the Database. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Where are the JavaDocs for `AgentBase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at what the error actually is:

```
 Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)
```

You are telling the VM to die and you do not have the rights to do this. If you had, you would cause anything else running on that JVM instance to die as well, possibly leading to a hang/crash.

Secondly your code is failing in the `ClipboardTest.main()` method, which you haven't posted any code for.

In the agent properties there is an option to add debug data. This will give you the exact line number that is causing the issue.

My guess is you have a `System.exit()` call in the `ClipboardTest.main()` . It shouldn't be there.

Comment: Simon, thank you so much. After removing System.exit() from ClipboardTest.main() the dialog is now correctly displayed.